# .NET Dropdown list with default value with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list where it produces the following:

with the possible values for SiteId:

```
 "Select Site"
 "1"
 "2"
 "3"
 "4"
```

Note that Select Site is the default value:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" DataSourceID = "siteDS" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSite_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="SiteName" 
            DataValueField="SiteId" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Select Site</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have the following query but not sure if there is a more better way

```
     // this checks to see if the value is Select Site or an actual siteid (1,2,3)
     int siteID = 0;
     int Site;
     bool result = Int32.TryParse(ddlSite.SelectedValue, out Site);
     if (result)
     {
        siteID = Site;
     }


     if (result)
     {
        NTDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM [tbl1] where siteId = " + siteID;
     }
     else
     {
        NTDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM [tbl1]";
     }
```

The reason why I have the if else is because we if the user selects: Select Site, I do not want to do the SELECT  as there is not siteId with value Select Site.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I recommend reading about [Sql Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you should really parametrize your queries.

Second, Since you have both DataText and DataValue properties, you can have "SelectSite" be the `Text` property and letthe `Value` to be 0 or -1 (or just empty).

Either way, you can do something like this:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(ddlSite.SelectedValue, out Site) && Site  > 0)
{
    // Parameterized SELECT
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

No need for both Site *and* SiteId

Answer (score 1):

```
// your initial item or better off you can add a client side validator
// preventing them from submitting the page with the initial value, also call Page.IsValid on server side to make sure they didn't hacked your client side validation.
if (ddlSite.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
   var siteId = 0;
   if (int.TryParse(ddlSite.SelectedValue, out siteId)
   {
      // then here build a helper for adding conditions if siteId is present.
      // try using parameterized queries for avoiding sql injection.
   }
   else
   {
      // call your same helper without siteId and it should be smart enough to
      // return a query without where clause.
   }
}
```

Here more information on [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).